# Why isn't addition defined by $a+0=a$ and $a+succ(b)=succ(a)+b$?

Tags: logic, definition, arithmetic, peano-axioms

The rule for addition is stated in the Peano axioms as:

$a + 0 = a$

$a + succ(b) = succ(a + b)$

But why couldn't we define it as

$a + 0 = a$

$a + succ(b) = succ(a) + b$

for example $3 + 4 = 4 + 3 = 5 + 2 = 6 + 1 = 7 + 0 = 7$

What makes the usual definition the preferred one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both definitions work fine. The usual definition has the advantage of fitting the "general form" of recursive definitions: when recursively defining a function $f$, we give a method for defining a "new value" $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ in terms of the "already defined" values $$\{f(y_1,...,y_n): y_1\le x_1,..., y_n\le x_n\mbox{ and some $1\le i\le n$ has }y_i<x_i\}.$$

The usual definition does this: it rewrites $Plus(a, Succ(b))$ in terms of $$Plus(a,b).$$ Your definition, however, rewrites $Plus(a, Succ(b))$ in terms of $$Plus(Succ(a),b).$$ It still works, of course, but it doesn't "strictly simplify" things: the ordered pair $(Succ(a), b)$ isn't really "smaller" than the ordered pair $(a, Succ(b))$.

---

Of course, this just pushes the question back one step: why is this approach preferred for general recursive definitions?

Well, the point is that reducing one input to zero *doesn't* generally trivialize things. In the specific case of addition we're comfortable asserting $Plus(a,0)=a$ for all values of $a$ right at the outset. But a general binary function $F$ might be quite complicated even when one of the coordinates is zero. In such a case, the approach you describe won't obviously help - by contrast, the approach described above *always* works since the relevant partial order on $n$-tuples is well-founded.

Comment: I don't understand what $y_1\le x_1,..., y_n\le x_n$ is trying to say exactly? Is there supposed to be both $x$ and $y$ in this?

Comment: @user686351 Yes, both $x$ and $y$ are important there (and don't forget the "some $x_i$ is strictly greater than the corresponding $y_i$" clause). It's saying that we're using "previously defined values" to compute our new value $f(x_1,...,x_n)$. E.g. consider $n=2$. Then we'd first compute $f(0,0)$. Next, we're ready to compute (say) $f(1,0)$, since the set of $y$-tuples corresponding to this $x$-tuple is just $\{(0,0)\}$, and we've already pinned down $f(0,0)$. Similarly, we're ready to compute $f(0,1)$. (cont'd)

Comment: Once we've computed those two, we're ready to compute $f(1,1)$ - note that we need *both* $f(1,0)$ and $f(0,1)$ to do this - e.g. maybe the rule we're using is $f(Succ(a), Succ(b))=f(Succ(a),b)+f(a, Succ(b))$.

Comment: I don't understand that inequality at all but is the general idea that when you have some function $f(a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n)$ then at least one $a_i$ should be smaller in a recursive call, and none should be larger?

Comment: @user686351 Yes, that's what it says: to compute $f(a_1,..., a_n)$, we're allowed to call all the "earlier" values - which is to say, the $f(b_1,.., b_n)$s whenever each $b_i$ is at most $a_i$ and some $b_i$ is smaller than $a_i$. (The idea being that when $a_i\ge b_i$ for each $i$ and $a_j>b_j$ for some $j$, the value $f(b_1,...,b_n)$ is computed before the value $f(a_1,..., a_n)$, so we're allowed to compute the latter using the former.)

Comment: I am not totally convinced that both theories (Peano as usual and with the modified axiom) yield the same class of models. Can this be easily seen? Also, @user686351 beware that often in recursive definitions the arguments are from wellordered sets, i.e. for every input $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ you will only have finitely many recursive calls down the chain. Precisely because in $\mathbb{N}$ you cannot go strictly (!) infinitely down.